Howto: C++ function that adjusts its return type to the callers needs
I have a malloc like function:
void * MyMalloc(size_t size) { return malloc(size); }
Now to use this for let's say a char * type;
char * charPointer = static_cast<char *>(MyMalloc(100));
How to get rid of the cast?
I can do this:
template<typename T> T MyMalloc(size_t size) {return static_cast<T>(MyMalloc(size));}
And the callling code is:
char * charPointer = MyMalloc<char *>(100);
This looks better, but is there a way to let the compiler do this for me?
Similar to auto, but my understanding of auto is that auto is determined by the return / assignment type not the needs of the caller.
What I want the calling code to look like is :
char * charPointer = MyMalloc(100);
Of course code like this would not work (and I would not want it to):
int val = MyMalloc(100);
I am not sure this can be done, but it it can be done, I'm sure somebody here knows.
Ty

auto charPointer = MyMalloc<char *>(100);?

Thank you, I was not being clear that what I wanted to get rid of is the <char *> .  I edited my question

Why do you need that in C++? new already does that.

"How to get rid of the cast?..." Don't.  Casting makes it clear what you're trying to do.

You can use a class type for this.  Classes can have a template conversion operator that will deduce the type you whish to convert to based on the expression it is used in.  That gives you a class that looks like
class MyMalloc
{
public:
    MyMalloc(std::size_t size) : ptr(malloc(size)) {}
    template <typename T>
    operator T() { return static_cast<T>(ptr); }
private:
    void* ptr;
};

and this lets you use it like
int main()
{
    char * charPointer = MyMalloc(100);
}

which you can see working in this live example.

How does the compiler deduce the type T to use for the template?

Wonderful this is exactly what I was looking for!!! Thank you! :Bow:
The compiler uses the type of charPointer and applies it to the template!
:)

@MarkRansom Its just the normal conversion operation.  During initialization the conversion operators of MyAlloc are considered and when you have a template conversion operator like this T get deduced as the type of the initializer.

Simple way to get a memory leak.

@MarkRansom Spec: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.deduct.conv

@Peter I use it  in a class that manages the pointer - so no leak
